# Woocommerce Rest API Product filters how it works?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to integrate the woocommerce rest APIs with my Applications. All the defaults operations like get all products, get products by category etc are working perfectly fine.

Can someone please let me know how are product filters implemented.?

bellow is my code.

```
$data = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'category' => '51',
    'per_page' => 100,
    'page' => 1,
    'attribute' => "Color",
    'attribute_term' => "Loft Gray"
);

$results = $woocommerce->get('products', $data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is really open ended.  You don't have any code samples that show what you have working, such as when you say, "get products by category etc are working perfectly fine."  What else do you need?

I can show you a couple examples, but who knows if it will help or not. I assume you already have a $woocommerce connection variable working...

**Example 1:**

```
$products = array();

$data = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'per_page' => 30,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'featured' => 1
);

$products = $woocommerce->get('products', $data);//returns the first 30 featured products that are published, and sorts them by date
```

**Example 2:**

```
$results = array();
$data = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'category' => '51',
    'per_page' => 100,
    'page' => 1
    //'filter[posts_per_page]' => '-1', //this was removed in v2 api
);

$results = $woocommerce->get('products', $data);//returns 100 published products of product category ID 51 (get this ID from your CMS)
//This can be used for pagination, since the filter functionality is removed
```

The API docs show you all the different properties you can access: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-products

I hope this helps.  If it doesn't, then please ask a specific question.

Comment: 1.  Take out  ''category' => '51',"
2. Attribute term is looking for an term ID (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-products)

Comment: @Jarom I tried your method to get fetch the featured products but it's not working still give same result even I used featured => 0 in my $data array it return me same 10 result of products 

I am using v3 api

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad Can you create a new question and post your specific query that isn't working (along with what you are trying to accomplish)?  It's hard to debug something that I can't see.  Link that question here and I'll take a look.